# Dynamic Class in Table with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to covert an CSV file to HTML table, but I need to give any table column a diferent class, so I can use only the columns that I need.

I have no ideia how to use a dynamic class (instead of td.class) name for every colums the script create, anyone here knows any solution for that?

My code:

```
$.each(items, function(itemCount, item) {

tableHTML += '<td class="' + td.class + '">' + item + '</td>';

});

tableHTML += '</tr>';
```

Thanks!

Comment: `class` is a reserved word, you should use `className` or just anything other than a reserved word. Your question is a bit confusing, are you trying to assign a class to each column?

Comment: what should "dynamic class name" reflect in your logic?

Comment: I wrote td.class just in my example, and yes, I need every column to have a diferent name. With Dynamic class name I mean a different class name for every column.

Comment: It it better to create element by using JQuery like `$tds.append( $('<td>').addClass(yourClassName).html(item));` Then out of the  loop `YourTableRowElement.append($tds)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) to append the column number:

```
var columnCount = 4;

$.each(items, function(itemCount, item) {
  var currentColumn = (itemCount % columnCount) + 1// add 1 because of zero index
  tableHTML += '<td class="column-' + currentColumn + '">' + item + '</td>';
});
```

I’m guessing you could probably get the `columnCount` dynamically, but would need to see the rest of your code to show that.